# Print statement defaults to first 'if' statement no matter the input given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm extremely new to python, so this code is probably a complete mess, but the issue I'm having is that the code is executing the first 'if' statement no matter what average is calculated (ie. the average calculated is a 76.0, but it's still executing an 'A' grade, rather than a 'C' grade). What am I doing wrong?

Also, just for information's sake, the code is supposed to have the user input four test scores and the code has to randomize a score for the fifth test in range of 70-85, calculate and return the average of all five test scores and assign a grade based off of the average.

```
def rand():
    import random
    num5 = random.randint(70,85)
    calcAverage(num5)

def calcAverage(num5):
    num1 = float(input("Enter the first test score: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter the second test score: "))
    num3 = float(input("Enter the third test score: "))
    num4 = float(input("Enter the fourth test score: "))
    print("\nThe random test score generater on your behalf was", num5)
    total = num1 + num2 + num3 +num4 + num5
    average = total // 5
    letterGrade(average)

def letterGrade(average):
    if average >= 90.00 and average <= 100.00:
        print("The average of five test scores is {:.1f}.".format(average),"and the letter grade awarded is A.")

    elif average >= 80.00 and average <= 89.99:
        print("The average of five test scores is {:.1f}.".format(average),"and the letter grade awarded is B.")

    elif average >= 70.00 and average <= 79.99:
        print("The average of five test scores is {:.1f}.".format(average),"and the letter grade awarded is C.")

    elif average >= 60.0 and average <= 69.99:
        print("The average of five test scores is {:.1f}.".format(average),"and the letter grade awarded is D.")

    else:
        print("The average of five test scores is {:.1f}.".format(average),"and the letter grade awarded is F.")

rand()
```

Comment: It looks ok to me with a quick glance. Can you double check your indentation? The contents of each if should be indented with a single tab relative to the if condition itself.

Comment: When I just copied and pasted and ran it it worked fine for me, but it looks like the person who edited it cleaned up the indentation -- try it now and see if it works for you now as well.

Comment: Fixing the indentation solved the problem, thank you guys so much!